# Grammatically restricted JVMModelInferrer inheritence with Xtext and XBase

Tags: xtext, xbase

The following canonical XBase entities grammar (from "Implementing Domain-Specific Languages with Xtext and Xtend" Bettini) permits entities to extend *any* Java class. As the commented line indicates, I would like to grammatically force entities to *only* inherit from entities.

```
grammar org.example.xbase.entities.Entities with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase

generate entities "http://www.example.org/xbase/entities/Entities"

Model:
    importSection=XImportSection?
    entities+=Entity*;

Entity:
    'entity' name=ID ('extends' superType=JvmParameterizedTypeReference)? '{'
//  'entity' name=ID ('extends' superType=[Entity|QualifiedName])? '{'
        attributes += Attribute*
        constructors+=Constructor*
        operations += Operation*
    '}';

Attribute:
    'attr' (type=JvmTypeReference)? name=ID ('=' initexpression=XExpression)? ';';

Operation:
    'op' (type=JvmTypeReference)? name=ID 
    '(' (params+=FullJvmFormalParameter (',' params+=FullJvmFormalParameter)*)? ')' 
        body=XBlockExpression;

Constructor:    'new'  
    '(' (params+=FullJvmFormalParameter (',' params+=FullJvmFormalParameter)*)? ')' 
        body=XBlockExpression;
```

Here is a working JVMModelInferrer for the model above, again where the commented line (and extra method) reflect my intention.

```
package org.example.xbase.entities.jvmmodel

import com.google.inject.Inject
import org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.JvmTypeReference
import org.eclipse.xtext.naming.IQualifiedNameProvider
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.AbstractModelInferrer
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmTypesBuilder
import org.example.xbase.entities.entities.Entity

class EntitiesJvmModelInferrer extends AbstractModelInferrer {

    @Inject extension JvmTypesBuilder
    @Inject extension IQualifiedNameProvider

    def dispatch void infer(Entity entity, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
        acceptor.accept(entity.toClass("entities." + entity.name)) [
            documentation = entity.documentation
            if (entity.superType !== null) {
                superTypes += entity.superType.cloneWithProxies
                //superTypes += entity.superType.jvmTypeReference.cloneWithProxies
            }

            entity.attributes.forEach [ a |
                val type = a.type ?: a.initexpression?.inferredType
                members += a.toField(a.name, type) [
                    documentation = a.documentation
                    if (a.initexpression != null)
                        initializer = a.initexpression
                ]
                members += a.toGetter(a.name, type)
                members += a.toSetter(a.name, type)
            ]
            entity.operations.forEach [ op |
                members += op.toMethod(op.name, op.type ?: inferredType) [
                    documentation = op.documentation
                    for (p : op.params) {
                        parameters += p.toParameter(p.name, p.parameterType)
                    }
                    body = op.body
                ]
            ]
            entity.constructors.forEach [ con |
                members += entity.toConstructor [
                    for (p : con.params) {
                        parameters += p.toParameter(p.name, p.parameterType)
                    }
                    body = con.body
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }

    def JvmTypeReference getJvmTypeReference(Entity e) {
        e.toClass(e.fullyQualifiedName).typeRef
    }

}
```

The following simple instance parses and infers perfectly (with the comments in place).

```
entity A {
    attr String y;

    new(String y) {
        this.y=y        
    }

}    

entity B extends A {
    new() {
        super("Hello World!")
    }
}
```

If, however, I uncomment (and comment in the corresponding line above) both the grammar and the inferrer (and regenerate), the above instance no longer parses. The message is "The method super(String) is undefined".

I understand how to leave the inheritance "loose" and restrict using validators, etc., but would far prefer to strongly type this into the model.

I am lost as to how to solve this, as I am not sure where things are breaking, given the role of XBase and the JvmModelInferrer. A pointer (or reference) would suffice.

[... I am able to implement all the scoping issues for a *non*-xbase version of this grammar ...]

Comment: this wont work. id rather leave the grammar as is and filter proposals and introduce validation

Comment: alternatively if you can guess the name of the Reference (e.g. from the node model) then you can use

`"qualified.Name.Of.Entity".typeRef` for the supertype

Comment: Is that not exactly what I am doing with my helper method getJvmTypeReference(Entity e)? The resulting qualifiedName is correct, but super(String) is not visible from B.

Comment: Not in what you have posted above

Comment: Thank you so much. I get what you mean and it works. The required line (in this case) is "superTypes += ("entities."+entity.superType.name).typeRef()". Please answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this won't work. you either have to leave the grammar as is and customize proposal provider and validation. or you have to use `"f.q.n.o.y.Entity".typeRef`. You can use `NodeModelUtils` to read the FQN or try something like `("entities."+entity.superType.name).typeRef`